# existence root without SUP or INF

Tags: real-analysis, radicals

I hope you could help me with the following task:

Show the existence of a root function:
$$\sqrt{*} : \mathbb{R}_{>0} \to \mathbb{R}_{>0}, a\to \sqrt{a}$$ with the property $$\sqrt{a}^2 = a $$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$. First have a look at the two subsets $X = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} | x^2 < a\}$ and $Y = \{ y \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} | y^2 > a\}$.

Now apply the completeness axiom to show that there is a 
$c \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x \leq c \leq y$ for all $x \in X$ and $y \in Y$. Use the following information: $$\epsilon \in \mathbb{R}$$ with $$0 < \epsilon < 1$$ the following statements apply: $$c + ε ∉ X, c - ε ∉ Y  $$ Conclude that $$c^2 ≥ a$$ respectively
$$c^2 \leq a$$

Our completeness axiom is:
$$\forall X,Y \subseteq \mathbb{R}: (( X \neq \emptyset \wedge Y \neq \emptyset \wedge \forall x \in X \forall y \in Y : x \leq y ) \implies ( \exists c \in  \mathbb{R} \forall x \in X \forall y : x \leq  c \leq  y )) $$

I've seen some proof but they all use supremum and infimum which we haven't learned yet. Neither maximum and minimum.

So here is my idea:
It's given by the task that "$x^2 < a$" and "$y^2 > a$". So $$x^2 < a < y^2$$
With transitivity we can say:
$$x^2 < y^2$$
This also means "$x < y$" since we are in $\mathbb{R}_{>0}$.
We have an element "$a$". With "$\frac{a}{2} < a < 2a$" we can say that $X$ and $Y$ are not empy. So we can apply the completeness axiom. There must be a "$c$" between "$x$" and "$y$". So $$x \leq c \leq y \Rightarrow x^2 \leq c^2 \leq y^2$$
With "$c + \epsilon \notin X$" and "$c - \epsilon \notin Y$" we have that $$c^2 + \epsilon^2 + 2\epsilon c \geq a$$ and
$$c^2 + \epsilon^2 - 2\epsilon c \leq a$$
I hope the proof is correct so far. Now I can't find the right steps to finish the proof. I hope you can help me out. Please keep in mind, I'm at the beginning of all this proving hullabaloo, so keep your answers non trivial

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can take the limit when $\varepsilon \to 0$ in $c^2 + \varepsilon^2 + 2 \varepsilon c \ge a$.

Comment: hello thanks for your answer. I know what you mean but strictly speaking we didn't learn the meaning of epsilon nor limits etc. So far we had:
First-order logic //
Set Theory //
Functions //
Relations //
Field axiom //
ordering axiom //

Comment: @Gribouillis is this a legit answer?

Because $ϵ^2 < ϵ$ the two Inequations depend only on $2cϵ$. So we have $c^2 - 2cϵ \leq a \leq c^2 + 2cϵ$. So we have $-2cϵ \leq a-c^2 \leq 2cϵ$. with the Archimedes' principle we have $a=c^2$?

Comment: The problem is that we don't know what properties you are allowed to use. For example it is true that $Y\neq \emptyset$ because $a+\frac{1}{2} \in Y$. Also $X \neq \emptyset$ if $a > 0$ and we define $X = \{x \ge 0, x^2 < a\}$ because $0 \in X$. It is also true that if $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$, then $x < y$ because $(y-x)(y+x) = y^2- x^2 > 0$ as $x^2< a < y^2$. You can apply the axiom and $c$ exists. Now if you take $1 > \epsilon > 0$, you can prove that $0 \le a - c^2 \le 2\epsilon c + \epsilon^2\le \epsilon (2 c + 1)$. I'll make an answer with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $a > 0$. We define $X = \{x \ge 0, x^2 < a\}$ and $Y = \{y \ge 0, a < y^2\}$. Then

- $X \neq \emptyset$ because $0\in X$.
- $Y \neq \emptyset$ because $(a+\frac{1}{2})^2 = a^2 + a + \frac{1}{4} > a$, so that $a+ \frac{1}{2}\in Y$
- For all $x\in X$ and $y\in Y$ one has $x^2< a< y^2$, hence $0 < (y^2 - x^2) = (y - x)(y + x)$ and this implies $y-x>0$ because $y+x\ge 0$. Hence $x < y$

From this, the completeness axiom says that there exists $c\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $\forall x\in X, \forall y \in Y, x \le c \le y$.

Let now $\epsilon \in (0, 1)$ be a real number. As $c+\epsilon > c$, one has $c+\epsilon \notin X$, hence $(c + \epsilon)^2 \ge a$. This implies
$a \le c^2 + 2 \epsilon c + \epsilon^2 \le c^2 + \epsilon(2 c + 1)$.

Suppose that $c^2 < a$, then $a-c^2>0$ and we can choose $\epsilon = \min(1,\frac{a-c^2}{2 (2c+1)})$, so that $\epsilon (2c+1)\le \frac{a-c^2}{2}$ and finally $a \le c^2 + \epsilon(2c+1)\le \frac{a+c^2}{2}$. This implies $a \le c^2$, a contradiction.

It follows that necessarily, $a \le c^2$. Suppose now that $a < c^2$. Then  one has $c > 0$ and for all $\epsilon \in (0, c)$, $0 < c-\epsilon <c$. In particular, $c-\epsilon \notin Y$, which means that $(c - \epsilon)^2\le a$. It follows that $c^2 - 2 \epsilon c+ \epsilon^2\le a$, hence
$c^2 - a \le 2 \epsilon c-\epsilon^2\le 2\epsilon c$. Choosing $\epsilon = \min(c, \frac{c^2-a}{4 c})$, we get $c^2 - a\le 0$, a contradiction.

It follows from all this that $a = c^2$, QED.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer! is there a way to work around ϵ=min(...) since it's not introduced yet in our script? let's say ϵ is the gap between $c^2$ and $a$ so ϵ has to be $a-c^2$ if $c^2 \leq a$ and it can not be 1 because the task says so 0<ϵ<1?
@Gribouillis

Comment: A way around the min is to say that $a \le c^2 + \epsilon(2c+1)$ implies $\frac{a-c^2}{2c+1}\le \epsilon$. As $\epsilon$ is arbitrary, it means that $\frac{a-c^2}{2c+1}$ is smaller than any number in $(0,1)$. If you are allowed to deduce that $a-c^2\le 0$ it leads to the same conclusion as before. In the same way, the second min can be avoided by the fact that $c^2-a\le 2\epsilon c$ implies $\frac{c^2- a}{2 c}\le \epsilon$ and you conclude again that $c^2-a\le 0$. Note that the second $\epsilon$ is in $(0, c)$ and not $(0,1)$.